# Information on the moderator candidates

Tags: discussion, election

[Yi Jiang](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/150097/yi-jiang) has put together a nice site that use the Stack Overflow API to display information on the moderator candidates.

Click here to see all the information. (Dead link removed)

The information presented is:

The nominees election

```
Answers/Questions on the main site and it's meta
Up-vote/down-vote ratio
Average reputation earned per post
Average reputation earned per day.
```

It displays what Yi Jiang considers to be noteworthy badges and whether the nominee has the badge and a summary of their recent activity.

The information is presented as is with no commentary.

It came about from this question on MSO [Moderator nomination possibly useful statistics](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/75454/59303)

Comment: Updated snapshot: http://pastehtml.com/view/b818tj0c8.html

Comment: Thanks for this.  I'd also asked a more recent question about statistics here http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/106540/elections-and-running-mass-data-stackexchange-queries

Answer (score 2):

While we wait for Yi to update his tool, you can already take a sneak preview:

Open Firebug or a smilar tool for live HTML editing.

Look for this line

```
<li data-sitename="Diy.Stack Exchange">
```

and replace it with

```
<li data-sitename="Security.Stack Exchange">
```

Then click on the Home Improvement button.

Displaying the correct site logo is left as an exercise to the reader...

Comment: ah - of course:-)

Comment: In chrome you can do this with the built in debug tools - CTRL+SHIFT+I lets you alter elements. Make the change as suggested above, then run audit present state.

Comment: you... you... hacker! you hacked the site!!

Comment: I had the same thought, @AviD - and what an appropriate  demo to post on the security site :)

Answer (score 1):

Good work folks.

If you're looking for a good resource to find out what the "Noteworthy Badges" mean, see

- [List of all badges with full descriptions - Meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions/67399#67399)